Transferring dataframe columns into dataframe rows
I have the following data:
ticker  company sector  industryGroup   industry    subindustry currency    1999-07-31  1999-10-31  2000-01-31  ...
CompA   Health  Health  Health      Health      Health      USD     12.3        23.33       33.1        ...
CompB   Machine Machine Machine     Machine     Machine     USD     32.1        34.44       23.1        ...                                                             
CompC   Machine Machine Machine     Machine     Machine     USD     32.1        34.44       23.1        ...
CompD   Machine Machine Machine     Machine     Machine     USD     32.1        34.44       23.1        ...

The above is just a sample of the data that is in excel file. The prices go till 02-01-2024 and there are more company row 541 companies to be exact. I wrote a code that takes the columns starting from the first date and puts them in a dataframe with the date column title. Next I took the second column prices and put them in a column with ticker symbol name. The output should be the same as below.
Date        CompA    CompB    CompC    CompD
1999-07-31  12.3     32.1     32.1     32.1
1999-10-31  23.33    34.44    34.44    34.44
2000-01-31  33.1     34.44    34.44    34.44

This is my code:
import pandas as pd

bvmf = pd.read_excel('Market.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = bvmf.iloc[0:1, 10:].columns

for i in range(len(bvmf)):
    ticker = bvmf['ticker'][i]
    df[ticker] = bvmf.iloc[i:i+1, 10:].values[0]

There are a lot of values.  Is there a better way to implement this code?


As a rule of thumb, avoid looping in Pandas:

for i in range(len(bvmf)):


Note that "transferring columns into rows" is called transposing. Use DataFrame.transpose or its alias DataFrame.T to swap the rows and columns without looping.

Manually selecting the date columns is error-prone:

.iloc[0:1, 10:]


Case in point, your original data apparently required 10:, but the sample you posted here actually requires 7:. Use DataFrame.filter to select the date columns instead of manually indexing them.



So instead of manually crafting a separate df, just manipulate the original bvmf dataframe and transpose it:
bvmf = (bvmf.set_index('ticker')                 # index will become column header after transpose
            .filter(regex=r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')  # select only YYYY-MM-DD columns
            .T                                   # transpose
            .rename_axis('date')                 # name the new index
)

Output (index named "date" and header named "ticker"):
ticker      CompA  CompB  CompC  CompD
date
1999-07-31  12.30  32.10  32.10  32.10
1999-10-31  23.33  34.44  34.44  34.44
2000-01-31  33.10  23.10  23.10  23.10

Optionally:

Use DataFrame.reset_index if you want the dates as a regular column like your original code/output.
Use pd.to_datetime to convert your dates into real datetime objects.

